# QCombobox custom behaviour with model

Tags: c++, qt

I have a model that return strings for DisplayRole. I did setModel for my QCombobox. But I need to place "setSeparator" instead of some values. So not the element itself have to be shown, it have to used as a mark to place a separator.
It is because I can't use setSeparator function to my QCombobox, It has no effect while setmodel is used.

How can I override with behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need is return a separator from your model. For me it is better to use special role for separator but string mark is can be used too.

```
class SeparatorModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    static const int SeparatorRole = Qt::UserRole + 5;

    explicit SeparatorModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;

private:
    QStringList m_strings;

};
```

Return your separator in `data` method

```
QVariant SeparatorModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (SeparatorRole == role)
    {
        if (index.row() == 3) //separator at row 3
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (Qt::DisplayRole == role)
    {
        return m_strings.at(index.row());
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

To prevent separator selecting also reimplement `flags` method

```
Qt::ItemFlags SeparatorModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags flags;
    flags = Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
    if (index.row() == 3) //separator at row 3
    {
        //no enabled for separator
    }
    else
    {
        flags = flags | Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
    }

    return flags;
}
```

Then you need to create custom item delegate

```
class SeparatorDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SeparatorDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

    /*
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    */
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    QSize sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;

};
```

In `paint` method draw line if data for separator role set

```
void SeparatorDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                              const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (index.data(SeparatorModel::SeparatorRole).toBool())
    {
        painter->drawLine(option.rect.left(), option.rect.center().y(),
                          option.rect.right(), option.rect.center().y());
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}
```

And in `sizeHint` method define the size of your separator

```
QSize SeparatorDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(index.data(SeparatorModel::SeparatorRole).toBool())
    {
        return QSize(0, 2);
    }

    return QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHint( option, index );
}
```

After all just set model and delegate to your combobox

```
ui->comboBox->setModel(&m_model);
SeparatorDelegate *delegate = new SeparatorDelegate(this);
ui->comboBox->setItemDelegate(delegate);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I almost come to the solution just like your, but few missunderstandings still left. So your post solve the day)))